# My countif will only work with hard-coded date criteria, not when it is dynamic, thus =today()-365

Tags: excel, excel-2003, countif

I'm using Excel 2003 SP3.

I'm trying to count dates in a column that are more than one year ago, so I am trying:

```
=COUNTIF(Library!G9:G10000,"<=today()-365")
```

But it gives me 0 when there is 1.  Funnily enough, if I hardcode the date 1 year ago, thus:

```
=COUNTIF(Library!G9:G10000,"<=16/05/2012")
```

then it works just fine.

Don't know if this is important by my range `(Library!G9:G10000)` includes some text value, e.g. "Unknown"
Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work since today() is a function and you have it stringified so excel will just interpret it as text.

An alternative that will work is

```
=SUM(IF(Library!G9:G10000<TODAY()-365,1,0))
```

This is an *array formula* and will require you to press Crtl+Shift+Enter rather than just Enter when you've finished typing it.

Your edit makes it harder. If there is also text or blank cells in the range then use

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(Library!G9:G10000),IF(Library!G9:G10000<TODAY()-365,1,0),0))
```

Again, this is an array formula.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For some reason it counts empty rows as if they meet criteria, the result is 9985, rather than 2! Can you help?

Comment: Just saw same from pnuts, any help with this?

Comment: Are you sure? Even with the longer formula I give? A blank cell returns false for IsNumber

Comment: Bathesheba, yep , it only counts rows where the date is on year ago. How can I get it to count rows that contain "Unknown"?

Comment: Is "Unknown" the only case where you want it to count, or do you want to count other text as well? I think you want to count any text but discount blank cells; is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be...

```
=COUNTIF(Library!G9:G10000,"<="&TODAY()-365)
```

...entered as a regular formula (as opposed to an array formula).